# Youtube Analytics API Channel

Tags: php, youtube-api

I tried to get likes and dislikes using youtube analysis api and now having problem setting the parameters. 
 There is a parameter called 'ids', which should be set to 'channel==USER_ID, where USER_ID identifies the currently authenticated YouTube user', but I am confused in the format of this, I don't know how to write this.
 I can got the userID, and I tried 'ids = channel == #userid#', but it wrong. So could someone tell me the right format to make this request, and give me a example.

This is my wrong request:
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?v=2.1&end-date=2012-10-10&ids=channel==##userid##&metrics=views,likes,dislikes&start-date=2010-10-10&access_token=##access_token##`

Comment: `There is a parameter called 'ids', which should be set to 'channel==USER_ID` where did you get this from? Link maybe?

Comment: @valentinas I don't understand, what does you mean please?

Comment: Where did you find that there is a parameter 'ids' and that it has to be set to "channel==USER_ID"? I was looking at the documentation but I can't find anything like that.

Comment: @valentinas https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/index#Parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode special symbols in urls, for example url encoded `=` would be `%3D`

So you can send request to `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?v=2.1&end-date=2012-10-10&ids=channel%3D%3D##userid##` and that `ids` parameter would translate to `channel==##userid##`

Comment: Thanks! But I got another error:{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}

Comment: I solve it!! I need permission using analysis api so I open it in google api console, then now I can get results! thanks!!!